# How to see print statment output while coding in enigma os

Tags: python, enigma2

I am new in Enigma dreambox. I am making simple login plugin. I want to see output of print statement so i can trace my plugin. So where can i find this output of print statement Or is there other way to trace program?

Comment: Do you mean 'trace' your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Enigma runs, but unless it's going out of its way to redirect your `stdout` somewhere, you probably can't find it anywhere.

What you probably *can* do is use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module (also see the [HOWTO/Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) if you've never seen `logging` before). You can log to a file that you read later, or even to a `syslog` daemon on your laptop somewhere else on the network.

Or just `open` a file somewhere and `write` to it (making sure to `flush` and/or `close` it appropriately). But `logging` takes care of a whole lot of stuff for you, so it's almost always a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about this. But print is better for read and less time consuming.  
Thanks for reply.

Comment: @user3932031: How is `print` either better to read or less time consuming? Really, you should only be using print for actually printing to stdout for console programs, and for quick&dirty debugging (and only when it works for quick&dirty debugging); for logging output, use `logging`.

Answer (score 0):

1- Telnet to your STB and enter "enigma2", Your STB will do a Restart GUI then you will be able to see debug messages

2- Run your plugin and check what you need

Comment: Yes, but before that, it is necessary to stop the enigma2 process, not start it again. This can be done, for example, by changing the linux run-level, through the `init 4` command, or simply by shooting down the enigma2 processes `killall -9 enigma2`, or a combination of both `init 4; sleep 5; killall -9 enigma2`. Only then is it possible to run Enigma2 from the Shell again, and watching the debug-log messages from the error console (on the display). Of course, redirecting the error console to a file is also helpful: `init 4; sleep 5; killall -9 enigma2; enigma2 > /tmp/e2debug.log 2>&1`.